# DiffUtil is not updating recyclerview when items are moved

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I implemented drag and drop in RecyclerView and is using `DiffUtil` to dispatch updates. But it appears items moves are somehow not dispatched by `DiffUtil` to the adapter. However, if I call `notifyItemMoved()` on the adapter, it works.

**In the Adapter**

```
fun updateItems(items: List<Item?>) {
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(MyDiffCallback(this.items, items), true)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        this.items = items
    }
```

**Repository**

```
fun swap(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
        val list = liveItems.value
        Collections.swap(list, fromPosition, toPosition)
        liveItems.value = list
    }
```

**Item**

```
data class Item(val id: String, @StringRes val title: Int, @DrawableRes val icon: Int) {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Item

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (title != other.title) return false
        if (icon != other.icon) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + title
        result = 31 * result + icon
        return result
    }
}
```

**MyDiffCallback**

```
class MyDiffCallback(private val oldList: List<Item?>?, private val newList: List<Item?>) :
    DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList?.size ?: 0
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList!![oldItemPosition]!!.id == newList[newItemPosition]!!.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList!![oldItemPosition]!! == newList[newItemPosition]
    }

}
```

Please note the `id` variable`is specific to each`Item`.

Comment: It seems you're passing a `NavDiffCallback` instance to `calculateDiff`, but your callback class is called `MyDiffCallback`.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim, it was a mistake I made while making changes to the code to post it here. I have corrected it, thanks.